# TFS Code Reviewer - Failed to Download (New Files)

Tags: tfs, tfs-code-review

Not sure how easy this question will be but here goes...

Using TFS 2012, I have submitted a code review (using the built-in code reviewer) on my changeset. When attempting to perform the review, the reviewer is clicking on a file and receives the error:

```
Failed to download '$/DPR12007 - XML File Splitter/Main/XML File Splitter/Bakkavor.XMLFileDesizer.WCF/ITradacomsSalesOrder.cs'.
```

Only for new files. Files that previously existed and have changed, download and display as expected.

I have added myself as a reviewer and I get the same error, I am a TFS Project Collection Administrator, so I don't think it's permissions. As far as I'm aware, I have every permission possible, but I could be mistaken I guess.

I have checked the obvious places such as event viewer for additional detail.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you verify that a shelveset was created, and that it has the appropriate files?

Comment: No Shelveset has been created. Should there be? A Changeset has been created and is correct.

Comment: When you create a code review from a changeset that isn't checked into source, it should bundle that into a shelveset.

Answer (score 3):

According to Microsoft this is a VS bug:

> We identified the problem in changeset based Code Reviews that affects all files that include change types branch, or rename.  This bug affects VS 2012 as well as 2013 Preview.  We have fixed the issue and the fix will be available starting in VS 2013 RC.

Source: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/794741/tfs2012-update-3-review-issue

Answer (score 0):

Do you see this problem every time you try to review an added file? Just to clarify, is it as simple as adding a new file to source control (without checking in) and requesting a code review for this change?

Comment: Thanks but no it's not that. Everything is definitely checked in and other developers can download. We use a dev branch to code in, where we check in routinely, then when complete, we merge to the main trunk and use that changeset to do the review on.